# Omega 4: despite of environment set to production, css-file is full of sass-debug-info

Tags: theming

I've built an Omega 4 subtheme, generating css through sass with 'drush omega-guard'. Despite my config.rb looks like this, all sass-debug-info{} rests in my generated css files:

```
saved = environment
environment = :production
if (environment.nil?)
  environment = :development
else
  environment = saved
end

output_style = (environment == :production) ? :expanded : :nested
line_comments = (environment == :production) ? false : true
sass_options = (environment == :production) ? {} : {:debug_info => true}
```

I there a wrong declaration in my config.rb or is there another setting overriding my config.rb?

Comment: Just restart your watcher

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see anything wrong with your config.rb but if you are having problems you can use the following to force compass to strip out the debug info.

```
compass compile -e production --force
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/1936986